# What's the convention in decoupling components in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, decoupling

Using `rails generate model`, I created two models/tables, policeman and policewoman.  They are lists of officers with many attributes (age, time in the field, case solved, etc.).  If I wanted to do a computation that determines who should get the next promotion to Sargent what is the conventional way to do it in rails?

I would want to create a new class just to deal with this situation, and hide all the complex computation (compare attributes between both lists) away from the caller.  So maybe in a controller, say Captain, under the method show I would do

```
class Captain < ApplicationController
  def show
    promotion = Promotion.new
    @ideal_sargent = promotion.sargent(Policeman.find(:all),Policewoman.find(:all))
  end
end
```

Where do I create this Promotion class?  Do I use `rails generate controller` to make it?  Or maybe make a gem for it?  Or even put it all in a model (I hear thin controllers fat models)?

EDIT:
Maybe [this](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159807075/skinny-controllers-skinny-models)?  If so, how do I create a model without a migration file being automatically made?

Comment: It doesn't belong in a controller, either, it belongs in a service object that knows about promotion logic.

Comment: So where and how do I create this service object?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general idea of decoupling it from models and from controllers is **a good one**. Although you confuse it a bit with controllers, generators and gems...

What you want to do is:

- introduce a service object which is plain ruby object
- put the logic for calculating promotion order inside it
- have it completely decoupled from controller and loosely coupled to police officers models

The interface to use it would be basically as you have already described:

```
# prepare some officers to choose from
officers = [PoliceWoman.find(1)] + PoliceMan.all
# returns the first ranking officer for promotion
to_be_promoted = SargentPromotionService.new.find_top_candidate(*officers)
```

Where to put this service model? I suppose it contains application specific logic, that isn't really useful outside of application. Therefore we put it in the app folder. But where in the app?

**A good practice is to setup the `app/domain` folder.** There you can put all the app specific domain models (service, policy, value objects, etc...). All you need to setup this folder is add it to the autoload paths inside the  `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/domain)
```

This way you have a clear separation of rails models (take care of persistence) and domain models - where you should put most of the application specific code. If your app is really simple and small you could also skip the `app/domain` folder and just use the `app/models`. And if you follow the approach to use plain ruby objects with loose coupling, you will get easily testable, maintainable, flexible and reusable code. =)

Comment: This is the confusing part of rails for me, as in other framework like spring-mvc, or yesod, controller "is" where the logic should be.  But the actual heavy lifting is done by some service that the controller can call, this service could be easily swapped or even reused in other application.  Putting everything in models seems wired, and in my view models should be simple, like a gateway to database table.  Also, creating a new "model" for heavy lifting is wired as it contradicts my view on models.

Comment: That how if I make the new app/domain folder and load it up, how do it create models?  I assume that if I use `rails generate model bluh` it would make many files in the default folders, so how do I specify where I want them?  Or it's best to manually make the class?

Comment: @HHC This logic absolutely does *not* belong in a Spring controller. In Spring it still belongs in a decoupled service object that can be injected into a controller or domain object. The "fat model" mantra is old and reasonable developers don't believe a model should be any fatter than a controller: things should be as fat, or thin, as they need to be.

Comment: Sorry I think your right, I think I may have phrased it wrong, what I mean was the controller is where it calls all the services to do work for it then aggregating all the outcomes then displays it.

Comment: Yes, this part of Rails is a bit confusing. The conventional way is to put it in the model, but it is wired as you say and it works for small apps only. This is where the <code> app/domain </code> approach comes handy and Rails supports it really well (you just need to enable it in the config). I do not use the generators for domain classes, as these are plain ruby classes. Although it could benefit from test classes being generated as well, but that is another topic..

Comment: @HHC What makes you think Rails should be any different? As a long-time dev in both Java and Ruby I've watched the Rails community's practices evolve to move towards what we've had to do in Java for years, it's just way, way easier, and more expressive, in Ruby.

Comment: @jurglic I see your point on not using the generators, however, I feel it is necessary to having test classes to cover it.  I'll open a new question to ask about it!  Also, I am curious, if it's a plain ruby class then why is it called domain model?  Wouldn't we call it a service?

Comment: @Dave Newton that is an interesting point you made.  I guess the programming philosophy is key?

Comment: @HHC Service is as good as well and even more specific. I just used  'domain model' because we talked about app/domain folder, which can include other domain classes as well..

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, I wouldn't create two tables to modeling the data. I would use a single table named polices, and keep a column as gender and another one as rank to differ policeman and policewoman, and different rank. Then I would put promote function as a class method inside the Police modal.

```
class Police < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.promote(param1, param2)
     ....
  end
end
```

In this way you can incapsulate the business logic inside the promote function, the caller can invoke it without knowing any complex computation in it. `Police.promote(a,b)`

Comment: This works at the the beginning when your app is small... but down the road when your app grows you end up with fat models, which is just one step better than fat controllers. For a more long-term approach extracting logic into domain object such as a service object is more appropriate. Altough, I agree in this case we are talking probably about a small app and it is also feasible. And totaly agree on the one table solution.

Comment: This is just a random example, it doesn't really matter how the segmentation is, what I want to know is "how" to decouple the application as I find it is good practice in the long run, but thanks for the replay!